# Launching 2 or more Java Spring Boot Projects in VSCode

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

I can run a Spring Boot application in VSCode by right clicking the main app JAVA class, and choosing Run/Debug action (knowing that I have the JAVA extensions installed).

I have a project/workspace with multiple Spring Boot applications, and I need to run the applications simultaneously.

I tried running each main application class, but VSCode only launches the first one I choose.

Any idea how to run both in VSCode without using external CMD tools?

Comment: Have you tried the extension [Spring boot dashboard](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-spring-boot-dashboard) ?

Comment: @TavoSanchez  It is not showing the projects and keeps the loading bar and never ends

Comment: You mean to run independent Spring Boot projects in current workspace simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After various trials, the Spring Boot Dashboard extension was the solution (which I had already installed), but it was not launching as the JAVA_HOME was pointing to 1.8+ version, while this extension needs 1.11+ version.

When changing the JAVA_HOME to JAVA 11, the extension worked, and I was able to launch both projects in the same workspace simultaneously.